# tmux string interpolation for session name

Tags: tmux

I am trying to make new session with the same name a as the current one with an extra `-2` on the end of the name.

```
bind C new-session -c "#{pane_current_path}" -s "#{session_name}"-2
```

The `session_named` does not interpolate the variable name it takes that texts literally, creating a session with the name `"#{session_name}"-2`

I am also running tmux 2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me in tmux 2.1 and 2.6. You need to detach the new session.

```
bind-key C run-shell 'tmux new-session -d -c "#{pane_current_path}" -s "#{session_name}-2"'
```

If you want to switch to the new session, you can use `switch-client` to move to this client to the "next" session.

```
bind-key C run-shell \
 'tmux new-session -d -c "#{pane_current_path}" -s "#{session_name}-2"' \;\
  switch-client -n
```

Note the backslash before `;` and also the ones used here to split the binding over 3 lines for legibility.

Comment: I get an error saying `'tmux new-session -d -c "/Users/Dylan" -s "session-2"' returned 1`

Comment: You'll get that if you already have a session named `session-2`. I just tried on tmux 2.6 and it was ok for me otherwise. Sorry, I don't know what else to suggest.

Comment: Ah, it does create the session, ocassionaly. Mostly it returns `1` - even if there is no sesion existing yet under the name `"#{session_name}-2"`

Comment: You might get some more information on the failure by using `tmux -v`. This prints debug into 2 files `tmux-*` in the current directory, but the info isnt easy to understand.

Comment: Ok, it seems to work. Can the command be modified to switch to the new session when it is created?

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: Can you use `#{session_name}` instead of the `*`?

Comment: See my update with `switch-client` instead.

Answer (score 0):

First off, when I tried this, I received a warning message about nesting `tmux` sessions, and `tmux` refused to perform the operation unless I first unset variable `$TMUX`, which I wasn't willing to do. So, I'm a bit curious why your binding works at all.

Being that you say that it does work, only that it creates a session with the incorrect name, maybe try this:

```
bind C new-session -c "#{pane_current_path}" -s "$(tmux display-message -p "#S")-2"
```

This attempt at a solution uses the shell's command substitution idiom `$(..)`.

Comment: This creates a session named `"$(tmux display-message -p `. Even changing `"#S"` to `'#S'` just makes a session called `$(tmux display-message -p '#S')-2`

Comment: Never mind, then. Sorry for the trouble, but I had the idiom working on a similar command, `create-window`, so I thought it would work also for this.

Comment: It might be interesting seeing your working command for create-window